# Apache Commons Configuration file import files

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

For Apache Commons Configuration, I am trying to load multiple java property files.

I was wondering if it's possible to "import/include" other files in one file so I only need to load the first file and the rest will all be imported.

E.g.

common.properties

```
include 'specific.properties'
propertyA=10
propertyB=20
```

specific.properties

```
propertyC=30
propertyD=40
```

So in the end I would have

```
propertyA=10
propertyB=20
propertyC=30
propertyD=40
```

---

Currently, I'm just using

```
CompositeConfiguration config = new CompositeConfiguration();
config.addConfiguration(new PropertiesConfiguration("common.properties"));
config.addConfiguration(new PropertiesConfiguration("specific.properties"));
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.
Copied from documentation:

> If a property is named "include", and the value of that property is the name of a file on the disk, that file will be included into the configuration.

In your case (common.properties):

```
include = specific.properties
propertyA = 10
propertyB = 20
```

specific.properties

```
propertyC = 30
propertyD = 40
```

See here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Using_PropertiesConfiguration

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i needed